# How to fix java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, glassfish

I'm trying to develop OSGI bundle with Datasource. When I try to deploy the bundle and the web application I get this error: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

This is the full error stack of Glassfish: http://pastebin.com/y4eGtF8B

This is the source code of the OSGI bundle with the datasource: download link - http://www.2shared.com/file/d0HN3HHD/SH_27.html

You can see the souce code here: http://pastebin.com/n86dEDai

This is the source code of the managed beans which calls the OSGI bundle: http://pastebin.com/yh15tPT8

Would you guide me how fix the code?

Best Wishes

Peter